Pair Fastq reads (output of a process) and then send as input to next process in nextflow
    // Generate error-free reads using dwgsim
    dwgsim_outputs = dwgsim(introduce_stop_codon.out.mutated_fa)

    // Create channel from dwgsim output file pairs
    paired_fq_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs('dwgsim_output/dwgsim_output/*_mutated_{1,2}.fq', checkIfExists: true)

    // Run snippy on dwgsim outputs
    snippy_outputs = snippy(reference_ch, paired_fq_ch)

I want to send pair reads i.e. fq1 and fq2 produced from dwgsim as samples to snippy along with reference file but Channel.fromFilePairs not working. How to do it?
I tried using Channel.fromFilePairs, it did not work.. I am expecting fastq file pairs.

In the workflow declaration, you should be able to send outputs from one process directly to another. You don't need to create the channels with fromFilePairs. It's likely not working because fromFilePairs runs at the start of the workflow, finds nothing, then stops.
Here is an example of how to send output from one process to another.
process dwgsim {
  input: 
    path(ref_genome)
    tuple val(id), path(reads)

  output:
    tuple, val("$id"), path("*processed.fastq"), emit: processed_reads

  script:
  """
  dwgsim $reads
  """
}

process snippy {
  input: 
    path(ref_genome)
    tuple val(id), path(processed_reads)

  output:
    path("$output")

  script:
  """
  snippy $processed_reads
  """
}

ref_genome = file( params.RefAnn, checkIfExists: true )
Channel
  .fromFilePairs('${params.input}/*_{1,2}.fq')
  .ifEmpty { error "Cannot find any files in ${params.input}" }
  .set { dwgsim_in } 

workflow {
  dwgsim( ref_genome, dwgsim_in )
  snippy( ref_genome, dwgsim.out.processed_reads )
}

Note, in DSL2, you can use channels more than once, so using ref_genome in two places works fine.
